# Cannot open own media files after AWS S3 download with libCurl + headers

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, libcurl

I already asked this question in the AWS Developer Forum without getting any response. So here goes:

I download my own media files from my own AWS S3 bucket using my own libCurl C++ application.

If I mark a file as public and download it with a simple libCurl GET request (no additional headers), the downloaded file works perfectly fine.
However, if I mark the exact same file as private and add headers to the GET request (Host, x-amz-date, x-amz-content-sha256 and the Authorization Header), I cannot open the downloaded file.

My question is:
Why does adding headers to the GET request alter the downloaded file?
And what can I do to fix this?

UPDATE: Using a hex editor I found out, that the HTTP response is written into the received file at the beginning.
How can I prevent that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It shouldn't.  What you're doing is very routine... but, how are you making the file private/public? Just toggling it in the console? (Because that also should be fine...)  Have you examined the resulting files with a hex editor?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michael-sqlbot for the suggestion of using a hex editor!

It appears, that the HTTP response is written into the received media file at the beginning. That explains, why I can't use these files...
But why is that and how can I prevent that?

Comment: And yes, I simply edit the properties of the files in the S3 Management Console to make them private/public. They are public now for testing, but in the long run they need to be private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Just had to remove this line from my code:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

Initially, I thought this line would allow me to add additional headers to my HTTP request...
Instead, it includes the HTTP response in the output, which was my problem.